# I/flutter (25473): Failed host lookup: 'shamo-backend.buildwithangga.id' I/flutter (25473): Failed host lookup: 'shamo-backend.buildwithangga.id'

Tags: flutter, authentication, host

I/flutter (25473): Failed host lookup: 'shamo-backend.buildwithangga.id'

`

```
import 'package:altamazee/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class AuthService {
  String baseUrl = 'https://shamo-backend.buildwithangga.id/api';

  Future<UserModel> register({
    required String name,
    required String username,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    var url = '$baseUrl/register';
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    var body = jsonEncode({
      'name': name,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    });

    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://shamo-backend.buildwithangga.id/api'),
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    );

    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(data['user']);
      user.token = 'Bearer ' + data['access_token'];

      return user;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Email sudah terdaftar');
    }
  }
}
```

`

please helpme to solve this
please helpme to solve this
please helpme to solve this
please helpme to solve this
[image]